# set a value in a hidden field in a thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-thymeleaf

I am completely new to frontend development and thymeleaf. So please excuse a beginners question I even could not answer alone after hours of searching.

I have a controller that is called from different frontend templates. In fact I try to find a way to make the controller aware who called it.
I thought of a field in the model that is filled not by the user but which is filled with a value from a hidden field  in the template itself.

So the model is something like

```
public class User {
  private String fromHiddenField;
  private String name;
  private String email;

  // getter and setter
}
```

An object of this class is processed by a simple template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<form action="#" th:action="@{/submitForm}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <!-- fill hidden field with a value-->
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{fromHiddenField}" name="hiddenfield" value="'valueSetInHiddenField'"/> 
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" name="name" id="name" size="30" maxlength="255" />
    <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" name="email" id="email" size="30" maxlength="255" />
    <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="send" />
    <input type="reset" name="form.button.cancel" value="reset" />
</form>
</html>
```

I have tried a lot but I could not find a way that fills the object in the template so that I can read the String value 'valueSetInHiddenField' from the field *fromHiddenField*  inside the controller.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not see the solution because it was too obvious.

```
<input type="hidden" th:attr="name='fromHiddenField'" th:value="'valueSetInHiddenField'"/>
```

sets the value as desired.

Helpful insights here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-hidden-inputs